# cant read text file via docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I am new to docker, my program reads text files that are stored in the resources folder.
this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /event_listener

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src ./src

COPY resources event_listener/recources

CMD ["python","./src/main.py"]
```

and this is where the file path is given to the constructor

```
class Contract:
    # initializing contract object
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.chainList = ChainList('resources/chain_objects.txt').chains
```

I create the docker container using `docker build --no-cache -t  event_listener .`
when I run it i get the following error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/chain_objects.txt'`

my code is built as following

```
|
|_src (source code)
|_resources(txt files)
          |_chain_objects.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried running your container and locate the file using `docker exec ... /bin/bash -c "find / -type f -name 'chain_objects.txt'"` ? Maybe you just copied the file in the wrong place...

Comment: "recources" in the Dockerfile looks like a typo.

Comment: yeah but still the same error

Comment: @TDk /event_listener/src/resources/chain_objects.txt
I got this result and it seems the filing is ok

Comment: @TDk it worked when i put the full path, is there a way to enter a relative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saw you caught that but be wary of typos like that (recources != resources)

I'd advise when copying files to use a full path to minimize mistakes.
turn:

```
COPY resources event_listener/resources
```

to this:

```
COPY resources /event_listener/resources
```

Inside the application use full path instead of relative ones.
from this:

```
self.chainList = ChainList('resources/chain_objects.txt').chains
```

to this:

```
self.chainList = ChainList('/event_listener/resources/chain_objects.txt').chains
```

the working directory you've set in the Dockerfile doesn't apply to your app running in the container based on it. If your framework allows you to set a `workdir` of some sort as its default searching location you can achieve that in such a way, but in order to avoid such mistakes always thrive to use a full path relative to your working environment (if you were to mention a file in the context of the project like `requirements.txt` use relative paths).

Second point, to help other developers with this magic string make it a constant, an environment variable, or a property you can import from an added file to the project

environment variables:

```
>>> import os
>>> user = os.environ['USER']
```

properties file:

ConfigFile.properties

```
[ExampleSection]
example = 1
```

the code:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('ConfigFile.properties')

print(config.get("ExampleSection", "example"))
```